# How generate .map file with clang?

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang

What is the equivalent flag of [/MAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/map-generate-mapfile?view=vs-2019) in Clang to generate .map file?

Comment: As of now, clang doesn't support this flag.

Comment: then isn't possible to generate .map file with clang?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the closest that I can think of for clang and the linker map file

`-Wl,-map,output.map`

Comment: Just tried using this flag with clang 17.0.0 and I got a `ld.lld: error: unknown emulation: ap` error.